# Server Push / HTTP Streaming on Windows Mobile / Windows CE

Tags: .net, http, windows-mobile, native, server-push

I find that HTTP Streaming / Server Push is quite promising for my project. Does someone have any clue on how to implement this in Windows Mobile?

.NET / Native / other implementations are welcomed. Preferably with permissive license.

some links on HTTP Steaming / Server Push:
- [Push Technology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology)
- [Streaming HTTP / Server Push](http://ejohn.org/blog/streaming-http-server-push/)
- [Cross-browser implementation of “HTTP Streaming” (push) AJAX pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112413/cross-browser-implementation-of-http-streaming-push-ajax-pattern)
- [XEP-0124: Bidirectional-streams Over Synchronous HTTP (BOSH)](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0124.html)

I was thinking of using some Qt XMPP library ([QXmpp](http://code.google.com/p/qxmpp/)) to do the job, but I'm not sure if it's up for the task and I also want to hear some opinions on this.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2019576/how-to-push-data-to-a-net-cf-client/2022833#2022833

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you could use [WebSync](http://www.frozenmountain.com/websync), a comet server for IIS/.NET. It's got full compact framework support.

Comment: WebSync URL changed to frozenmountain.com/products-services/websync

Answer (score 0):

You might consider Nirvana (http://www.my-channels.com/). It supports lots of Enterprise, Web and Mobile platforms including dot Net CF.